# есть массив состоящий из кнопок и надо каждой кнопке задать текст как это сделать?

Tags: java, javafx

создаю массив кнопок таким образом:
`Button[] button = new Button[29];`
добавляю в него кнопки :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
        button[i] = new Button();
        button[i].setOnAction(this::handleButtonAction);

    }
```

даю кнопке текст :

```
  button[0].setText("asdf");
```

ошибка:
`javafx.fxml.LoadException`

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный текст ошибки и полный код инициализации графического интерфейса.

Comment: `button[i] = new Button("asdf");`